# Prove $m-n$ and $2m+2n+1$ are coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I have a small problem:

> Let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $2m^2+m = 3n^2+n$.
>   Prove that $m-n$ and $2m+2n + 1$ are perfect square.

My work:

We have $$(m-n)(2m+2n+1) = 2(m^2-n^2) + m-n = n^2.$$

So, we need to prove that $m-n$ and $2m+2n+1$ are coprime. But I don't get further. Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 No, read the whole question. He wants to prove they're coprime, since that is the only thing he needs to finish the problem.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 It's enough to prove they're coprime to prove they're perfect squares.

Comment: Ok...He should add that statement , but he should write the actual question..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 He made his question clear at the end.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680972/if-m-n-in-mathbb-z-2-satisfies-3m2m-4n2n-then-m-n-is-a-perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume for contradiction $p\mid \gcd(m-n,2m+2n+1)$ for some prime $p$.

But then $p\mid n^2\iff p\mid n$, and so $p\mid m-n\implies p\mid m$.

However, $p\mid 2m+2n+1$ is then impossible.